# Why double if only works for yes? Does not work for no?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

**Code:**

```py
a = 1
b = 2

if a == 1:
    if b == 2:
        print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Because you have an `else` for the condition `a==1`, but none for `b==2`, only that condition (a<>1) will be able to print no.

Comment: Should it print "no" when one of the conditions is true or both of them?

Comment: It is very unclear what your questions is. Please rephrase with what you thought would happen and what actually happens

Comment: A better solution would probably be something like `if a == 1 and b == 2:` and keep it down to a single if statement (and therefor a single else)

Answer (score 1):

If you change a to 3, it will print No. If b is anything else than 2, you will print nothing